# Create CLR assembly and available group?

Tags: sql-server

I created a CLR stored procedure in C# and I will need to deploy it to SQL server available group cluster.

Can I just copy the assembly DLL to the hard drive of the primary server and run "create assembly" on the primary server?

Or I will need to copy the DLL to all the server and run create assembly separately on the server in the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this only once per database, regardless of whether it's in an availability group or not. Once you run the `create assembly` statement, the bits are inside the database so you don't even need the dll file anymore.